# compiler doesn't finish process

Tags: c++, multimap

I have a multimap which key is short and value is the other multimap

```
std::multimap<short,std::multimap<short,short>> multimap
```

now I want to do it`

```
std::multimap<short,short> &a=multimap.find(0)->second;
std::pair<short,short> z={1,2};
a.insert(z);
```

It compiles fine. But when I run it it just stops and doesn't finish the process, It even doesn't throw any runtimeerror. Have any ideas? Thanks in advice.

Comment: run under a debugger or through *valgrind*

Comment: We can't reproduce your error and help you if you don't give us a [Minimal and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: what reference do you expect to get in *a* ? does `find` return `end` in your case ?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5910058)

Comment: ***It compiles fine*** contradicts the title of your question. Note that the job of the compiler is 100% complete when it finishes the compilation of your code. Your title probably should be adjusted to note that the execution of your program terminates unexpectedly or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having

```
std::multimap<short,std::multimap<short,short>> multimap
...
std::multimap<short,short> &a=multimap.find(0)->second;
std::pair<short,short> z={1,2};
a.insert(z);
```

If `find` returns `multimap::end` that one shall not be dereferenced, but you do and get a reference to `second`, the behavior is undefined when later to use that reference to `insert`.

So of course check if `find` succes, like

```
  std::multimap<short,std::multimap<short,short>> multimap;
  std::multimap<short,std::multimap<short,short>>::iterator it = multimap.find(0);

  if (it == multimap.end()) {
    ...
  }
  else {
    std::multimap<short,short> &a = it->second;

    std::pair<short,short> z={1,2};
    a.insert(z);
  }
```

---

Out of that your title "compiler doesn't finish process" is not very clear, the execution is not the one you expect, but the compiler does not run the process

Answer (score 2):

If `multimap` does not have an item with key `0`, then `multimap.find(0)` returns an iterator that is not dereferenceable. Always check the return values of such calls before dereferencing the iterator.

```
auto iter = multimap.find(0);
if ( iter != multimap.end() )
{
   std::multimap<short,short> &a = iter->second;
   std::pair<short,short> z={1,2};
   a.insert(z);
}
else
{
   // Decide what to do
}
```